# Django test not actualizing object

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I have a django rest framework test, it is just a wrapper over regular django tests that works exactly the same way. The code looks like this:

```
user_created = User.objects.create_user(first_name="Wally", username="farseer@gmail.com", password="1234",
                                            email="farseer@gmail.com")

client_created = Client.objects.create(user=user_created, cart=cart)

data_client_profile["user"]["first_name"] = "Apoc"

response = self.client.put(reverse("misuper:client_profile"), data_client_profile, format="json")

client_created.refresh_from_db()  # Tried this too

self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

self.assertEqual(client_created.user.first_name, data_client_profile["user"]["first_name"])
```

So, I want to update the `client_created` object with some data in the dict `data_client_profile`, then `assertEqual` that the `client.user.first_name` is  "Apoc".

Here is the code in the view, I added two `pdb.set_trace()` that will help more than just pasting all the code:

```
        pdb.set_trace()

        client_existing_user_obj.phone = phone
        client_existing_user_obj.user.email = email
        client_existing_user_obj.user.first_name = first_name # Updating here!
        client_existing_user_obj.user.last_name = last_name
        client_existing_user_obj.user.save()
        client_existing_user_obj.save()
        pdb.set_trace()
```

The first pdb break shows this:

```
(Pdb) client_existing_user_obj.user.username
u'farseer@gmail.com'  # Make sure I'm updating the created object
(Pdb) client_existing_user_obj.user.first_name
u'Wally'  # First name is not updated yet
```

The second pdb break shows this:

```
(Pdb) client_existing_user_obj.user.first_name
u'Apoc'  # Looks like the first name has being updated!
```

But, when the test runs I get the error:

```
self.assertEqual(client_created.user.first_name, data_client_profile["user"]["first_name"])
AssertionError: 'Wally' != 'Apoc'
```

Why does it fail? I even call `refresh_from_db()`. I confirm it has being updated in the view, but then in the test it looks like it has not. I don't understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the docs for [`refresh_from_db`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db) say that `client_created.user` will not be refreshed by `client_created.refresh_from_db()`, because `client_created.user_id` has stayed the same:

> The previously loaded related instances for which the relation’s value is no longer valid are removed from the reloaded instance. For example, if you have a foreign key from the reloaded instance to another model with name `Author`, then if `obj.author_id != obj.author.id`, `obj.author` will be thrown away, and when next accessed it will be reloaded with the value of `obj.author_id`.

Therefore you need to refresh `client_created.user`:

```
client_created.user.refresh_from_db()
```

or refetch `client_created` yourself:

```
client_created = Client.objects.get(pk=client_created.pk)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the *user* you need to refresh from the database, since that's the object you're modifying:

```
user_created.refresh_from_db()
```